# Why would CSS stop working when a snippet is made into a directive?

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I made a directive for a specifically styled Comment Item (ionic)

`<comment-item file="commentItemDefault" comment="obj.comment></comment-item>`

All of the code is the same with in the template `commentItemDefault`

```
<ion-item ng-class="{ 'read': comment.read }">
  <h2>{{comment.from}}</h2>
  <p>{{comment.copy}}</p>
</ion-item>
```

The `read` class is never applied.

```
.read{
  background-color: #660000 !important;
}
```

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
.read{
    background-color: #bddef4 !important;
    .item-content{
        background-color: transparent !important; 
    }
}
```

in ionic you have to bypass the `.item-content` class to see custom item colors and styles.

I hope this helps.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's another syntax I'm unaware of, but it looks like you're doing an odd variation of ng-class's map syntax, which looks like this:

`<ion-item ng-class="{ 'read': comment.read }"> ... </ion-item>`

Comment: I just typed it wrong. I wasnt able to open git at work and was typing from memory...i have what you typed though

Comment: Is `replace` set to true for `ion-item`? If so, your `ng-class` isn't going to survive the replace to actually do anything.

Comment: I had to set .item-content background to transparent. it was covering my .item background styles

Comment: If you've solved your problem, you should post an answer and mark it as such.